# filtering pooled data from a dataframe and assigning it to a new dataframe in R

Tags: r, select, filter, contains

I am trying to filter out some pooled data from a dataframe and assigning it to a new dataframe however I keep getting an error and I am really confused on how to fix this
[image: Here is a picture of the dataframe with the pooled data]

I tried doing:

```
filt_covid_df <- covid_df %>% filter("location")
```

but it kept giving me an error as shown in the picture

[image: Here is the error I keep getting]

Comment: To include specific entries, you would use `filter(location %in% c("one thing to include", "another one", "third thing"))`. To exclude, you'd use `filter(!location %in% c("not this", "or this", "nor this"))` For more, see https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#filter-rows-with-filter

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064). `filter("location")` doesn't really make sense. How exactly do you want to filter the location? You aren't giving dplyr enough info to tell it what you want to keep.

Comment: Thank you Jon Spring, I did the !location code and it worked out!